# AWS SES - Generate a unique email address per cognito user for a domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is it possible to create a unique SES email address per user for a verified domain?

We would like to do this so the user can forward attachments to their generated email address which will be inserted into S3 and processed by a Lambda trigger.

As an example, we have the verified SES identity domain "**example.com**"

When a user signs up, we would generate a unique email address **randomuniquestring@example.com**

Then the user would email attachments to that unique email address which will be processed by the backend and deleted automatically after.

Can this be achieved with SES or how can we use other technology to achieve?

Perhaps a solution is to have a single email address with the verified domain and to process attachments from all users? How could we identify which user emailed the attachments?

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible way is to create a Rule or a Rule Set in SES when a new user sings up.

The rule will be triggered just when the receiver is `randomuniquestring@example.com` and it will trigger the lambda that you need.